# How to limit/round elements of a tensor to 4 decimal places on GPU in Torch?

Tags: machine-learning, lua, neural-network, conv-neural-network, torch

I wonder, how can I truncate the precision of tensors on GPU to a desired decimal places? I want to limit the elements in a tensor to 4 decimal places but it seems that there is no built-in function in Torch to do this efficiently and effectively. Does anyone know how one can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not straight-forward to round the numbers in a tensor but an easy solution (which kind of serves for my purposes) is to just convert the tensor to half-precision as follow:

```
require 'cutorch'

temp = torch.rand(3, 3)
temp = temp:cuda()
temp = temp:cudaHalf()
```

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would for sure be to first convert the tensor to numpy and then use numpy's round function. For example:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

x = torch.randn(size = (30, 10, 10)).numpy()
print(x)
x = np.round(x, 4)
print(x)
```

Just compare the print-out statements of `x` before it is rounded and afterwards.